# Find duplicates in unsorted string array - O(nlogn)

Tags: java

I got array of String hash values, for example: "123-51s-12as-dasd1-das-41c-sadasdgt-31". I need to find out if there are any duplicates. The catch is, that I need to find them all in O(nlogn).

1) My idea:

To do this I could use binary-search algorithm. But binary-search works only for sorted numeric array. So I ask: Is there any way to sort string array ?

2) I am open for any other answers. My question is:
**How to find all duplicates in array of unknown strings - nlogn.**

Comment: If you use a hash table, you can find the duplicates in O(n) time.

Comment: I use string table. And those strings are hash-values.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since the time bound is `nlog(n)`, you could safely first sort the array, and then do a scan from left to right to check for duplicated strings.

Comment: Ok, so: 1. How to sort array of strings, that can't be simply coverted to int.2. If i scan from left to right for 'n' elements. It means that I will do n x n comparsions. And it is O(n^2)

Comment: 1. Java could sort String; 2. You just have to compare the current one with the next one, since it is sorted, if two elements are the same they'll be sorted to be next to each other.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `Set<String>` and insert your strings into it by cycling the array: walking the array is O(n), inserting is O(log(n)). If `.add()` returns false, this is a duplicate:

```
public Set<String> getDups(String[] hashes)
{
    Set<String> all = new HashSet<String>();
    Set<String> ret = new HashSet<String>();
    for (final String hash: hashes)
        if (!all.add(hash)) // already seen
            ret.add(hash);
    return ret;
}
```

Comment: `Set` by itself has no performance guarantees.  `HashSet` has amortized constant time insertion, not O(log(n)).